# Executing terminal app and Triggering go golang visual studio code debugging with delve from terminal

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

I would like to tigger visual studio code debugging of *.go files from the terminal.

I also need to be able to pass command line arguments which I have already working.  These command line arguments are set based on bash variables I exported.  I want to attach through the terminal without going directly in visual studio to attach.
Is this possible?

e.g. something like dlv debug *.go --user=john

Comment: For command line args, use `args` attribute from launch configuration.
I don't know what you mean by using "breakpoints and all other features". vscode go extension supports breakpoints and many other features. If you just meant launching the debugger from the terminal, I think you may consider to launch a dlv headless server and use remote/attach mode as described in https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging#connecting-to-headless-delve-with-target-specified-at-server-start-up

Comment: to pass args from command line, `dlv debug [list of .go files or package path] -- --user=john`

Comment: This is a command line app so it finishes and closes before I can attach in in visual studio code.  What I want is that it attaches automatically, while still having access to the arguments I pass, which are are based on bash variables (they are secrets I do not want to include in launch.json).